# Make ROS2 use zero-copy

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I would want an intra-process communication without copying of messages. Does it work by default?

For now, the publisher code is:

```
auto message = make_unique<std_msgs::msg::String>();
message.get()->data = someString;
cout << "INPUT " << (void*)&(message.get()->data) << "\n";
native.get()->publish(message);
```

which calls `publish(std::unique_ptr<MessageT, MessageDeleter> & msg)`.

The subscriber code is:

```
    ...subscriberMethod(const std_msgs::msg::String::UniquePtr message) {
    cout << "OUTPUT " << (void*)&message.get()->data << "\n";
    string text = message.get()->data.c_str();
    ...
}
```

This subscriber method is directly registered with `create_subscription`. I get an output like

```
INPUT 0x7fab70000b60
OUTPUT 0x7fab64000b60
```

that is, there is some copying in between, even if both the publisher and the subscriber are within the same process. I tried the above with `shared_ptr`, but the addresses were also different.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310333/make-ros2-use-zero-copy/) by [uthinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/37306/uthinu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2018-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Hello, I would want an inter-process communication without copying of messages. Does it work by default?

No, not right now, see:

https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/9da1b95ece1f13aba1b7c1e4be832094f99e74c5/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/node.hpp#L106

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1